# How to get the value for Days in this code?

Tags: c

I am trying to show the average temperature for 4 days, the highest and lowest. The code works perfectly to show the average and highest/lowest value of the 4 days. The problem is trying to show in which day it occurred.

I know that I don't need to use arrays for it, I thought it was easy if I used it. So, here's the code. How can I improve it, to get the day of the highest/lowest value insert by the user?

```
int high[NUMS], low[NUMS];

int maximum = 40;
int minimum = -40;

int i, day;

float total, average;

printf("---=== IPC Temperature Analyzer ===---\n");

for (i = 0; i < NUMS; ++i) {

    do{
        printf("Enter the high value for day %d: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &high[i]);
        printf("Enter the low value for day %d: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &low[i]);  


       if ((high[i] > maximum) || (low[i] < minimum) || (high[i] < low[i])){
                printf ("Incorrect values, temperatures must be in the range -40 to 40, high must be greater than low.\n");
        }

    } while((high[i] > maximum) || (low[i] < minimum) || (high[i] < low[i]));

    if((high[0] < high[i]))
       high[0] = high[i];

    if ((low[0] > low[i])) 
       low[0] = low[i];

    total = total + (high[i] + low[i]);

}

 average = (total / (NUMS * 2));

printf("The average (mean) temperature was: %.2f\n", average);
printf("The highest temperature was %d, on day %d\n", high[0], day);
printf("The lowest temperature was %d, on day %d\n", low[0], day);

return 0;
```

Comment: save index to `min_i` and `max_i`

Comment: With `dayhi = i;` and `daylo = i;`, you need two variables as they might not be the same day. They should be initialised to `0`, because the range test during the first iteration will never be true. Moreover I would also use dedicated variables for the max and min temperature and not overwrite element [0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way without changing very much your code is declaring two variables `day` instead of one:

```
int day_low = 0;
int day_high = 0;
```

Then change your `if` conditions below for these:

```
if((high[0] < high[i])) {
   high[0] = high[i];
   day_high = i;
}

if ((low[0] > low[i])) {
   low[0] = low[i];
   day_low = i;
}
```

And finally:

```
printf("The highest temperature was %d, on day %d\n", high[0], day_high);
printf("The lowest temperature was %d, on day %d\n", low[0], day_low);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. But now works perfectly if the highest or lowest values are not on the first day. If you insert a high value on day 1 for example, the day shows randoms numbers.

Comment: I update my answer to solve the problem of day 1. Just initialise to 0 the "day" variables

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. I had to add to variable and initiate as 0 as mentioned.

But was still wrong. Day one was showing as "Day 0". To fix it I add +1.

```
if((high[0] < high[i])){
       high[0] = high[i];
       highestDay = i + 1;
    }

    if ((low[0] > low[i])){ 
       low[0] = low[i];
       lowestDay = i + 1;
    }
```